# JavaFX number axis getParent coordinates are offset compared to the chart it is a child to

Tags: javafx

Can anyone explain in the below code, why using a getParent call on a number axis gives a different scene to local conversion for mouse events compared to the chart which should be it's parent (or my understanding is incorrect). Using the number axis to get the parent and to then do the conversion shows a layout applied to it, and I don't understand why. You can run the code and click to see this.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ChartLocal extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        final StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 2);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 2);
        final LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        pane.getChildren().add(chart);
        root.setCenter(pane);

        chart.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("----");
                System.out.println("Event source :" + event.getSource());
                System.out.println("Chart        :" + chart);
                System.out.println("Axis parent  :" + xAxis.getParent());

                System.out.println("Pos 1 : " + event.getX() + "," + event.getY());
                System.out.println("Pos 2 : " + chart.sceneToLocal(event.getSceneX(), 0).getX() +
                        "," + chart.sceneToLocal(0, event.getSceneY()).getY());
                System.out.println("Pos 3 : " + xAxis.getParent().sceneToLocal(event.getSceneX(), 0).getX() +
                        "," + yAxis.getParent().sceneToLocal(0, event.getSceneY()).getY());

            }
        });

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: In short, because the parent of the axis is not the chart, but another node which is a descendent of the chart (you can see this from your output, where you include the "Axis parent"). In other words, the scene graph hierarchy of the chart is more complex than you are assuming.

Comment: In the current implementation, `axis.getParent().getParent()` will give you the chart, but there's no real guarantee that won't change in future releases. You could always do something like `Parent c = axis; while (! (c instanceof Chart) && c != null) c = c.getParent();`, after which `c` would be the chart as long as the axis is some descendent of the chart (and give `null` otherwise). What are you actually trying to do: maybe there's a different solution to the one you are pursuing.

Comment: It was partly curiosity, but came about from trying to get the axis origin in the line chart coordinate frame of reference. I was using axis.getDisplayPosition(0), and then axis.localToParent(...) on the position, and was seeing occasional offsets on resizing the chart. I can use axis.localToScene(...), and then chart.sceneToLocal(...), but at the time I didn't have the chart reference directly available, hence why I was doing it all off the axis. Walking up the graph seems a reasonable approach also, so thanks for the help.